# Is there any analogue to NetBeans RCP in .Net/C# world?

Tags: c#, java, .net, netbeans, rcp

In Java world, NetBeans is not only an IDE, but also an RCP (rich client platform) - a versatile extensible foundation for building desktop modular applications. Is there anything alike in .Net/C# world?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is, unfortunately, "No". Some things to think about here though:

- Visual Studio, which is the de-facto standard IDE in the .NET world, is commercial and although it's extensible, it's not intended to be used as a generic RCP platform.
- [Sharp Develop](http://sharpdevelop.net/opensource/sd/) is an open source .NET IDE. I don't know that it's meant to be used as an RCP and have never seen it used that way. However, its architecture and design is well documented so that it could be indirectly leveraged for a .NET rich client app.
- Although not a IDE by any stretch of the imagination, [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) represents the current best practices, patterns and guidance that is used for most of the new .NET rich client development that I see. I would expect that this would be the proposed approach for any .NET rich client proposed for one of my projects.